# js округление до 2 знаков

Tags: javascript, jquery

как из этой:

> 173.39999999999998

цифры округлять до:

> 173.40

на jquery почему этот код не работает:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#test').toFixed(2)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">159.5661651</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вся проблема в jQuery.
$('test') вам возращает не число, и не текст, и даже не DOM элемент, а некую jQuery конструкцию. Из неё правда можно вынуть всё перечисленное, но зачем, если можно сразу взять то что нужно?

```js
console.log(parseFloat(test.innerText).toFixed(2))
```

```html
<div id="test">159.5661651</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо работает. Забыл об `int'е`

Answer (score 2):

> parseFloat($('#test').innerHTML).toFixed(2) - так наверное должно работать. Округлять нужно число, а не элемент страницы

Comment: parseInt и toFixed это заявка на успех)

Comment: да))) чёт не сообразил. исправил